# insert multiple rows mysql from another table

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I tried this function does not work me.

```
$clv = Execute("SELECT `id_propiedades` FROM `propiedades` WHERE `gestor`=2 ORDER BY `propiedades`.`id_propiedades` ASC");
$estado = "1";
foreach (array($clv) as $valor) {   
$row_data[] = "('$valor','$estado')";
}
$sInsertSql3 = " INSERT INTO `cuotas` (`clv_cuota` ,`estado`) VALUES".implode(',', $row_data);
$GLOBALS["conn"]->Execute($sInsertSql3);
```

I get this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqlt_driver_ResultSet could not be converted to string in ...

any suggestions

Comment: Which line does the error refer to in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the single query:

```
'INSERT INTO cuotas (cuotas.clv_cuoata, cuotas.estado) SELECT propiedades.id_propiedades, 1 FROM propiedades WHERE gestor=2 ORDER BY propriedades.id_propiedades ASC'
```